# Hard disks cataloguer needed

Tags: hard-drive, search

22.04.
I would like to achieve something like I use in my Mac: Neofinder is a program that builds a database with all the directories and files (and some of their properties) of any hard disk I ask to catalog. It has an updater to regularly update data of the connected HDs.
It is very useful because I also can search on disks that are not connected but they were catalogued.

I installed [Catfish](https://pkgs.org/download/catfish) but it makes a live search only on the selected HD (it has a bug: cannot 'Show in File Manager' option).

Also tried [Katalog](https://sourceforge.net/projects/katalogg/). It is a better approach but it is to slow (I understand that first time cataloging a disk would be slow). It creates a csv file.
I scanned a disk and [Create Catalog](https://github.com/StephaneCouturier/Katalog/wiki/Create) goes to 'Katalog is not responding' for a long time, then Force Quit (this is after it gets the HD file/dir tree).
I'm not asking here for help on Katalog, just for another program option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *QDirStat*'s *qdirstat-cache-writer* in a *cron* job to keep information about permanently mounted filesystems up to date, and trigger it manually for removable disks.

If you use its `-l` option, you can use those files as a very quick `locate` replacement with a simple `zgrep` call.

And of course you can load each of those files into the *QDirStat* GUI to inspect that directory tree visually.

See

https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat/blob/master/scripts/README.md

--

HuHa (QDirStat author)

Comment: It sounds good! I've created 3 disks caches individually from GUI. Lots of useful info.  I guess I would have to create a script to search/locate a file over all caches in a snap instead of one by one

Comment: Actually, no: The paths are unique, and you can simply do `zgrep mysearchedfile cache*.gz` over all the cache files at the same time. You can add more bells and whistles with a script, though.

Comment: Great! It would be nice to have cache*.gz files listed and zgrep in GUI.  I mean a list of cache files with checkboxes, check all option, input for the key and a Search button to perform zgrep command.